# Calculate Year-Over-Year Change in DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have `DataTable` mocked-up below:

```
+----+------+-------------+--------+
| ID | YEAR | PERSON_NAME | AMOUNT |
+----+------+-------------+--------+
|  1 | 2004 | BARBARA     |    500 |
|  2 | 2004 | BOB         |    100 |
|  3 | 2004 | JANE        |     30 |
|  4 | 2004 | JOHN        |    200 |
|  5 | 2005 | BARBARA     |    505 |
|  6 | 2005 | BOB         |    150 |
|  7 | 2005 | JANE        |     15 |
|  8 | 2005 | JOHN        |    215 |
| 10 | 2006 | BARBARA     |    523 |
| 11 | 2006 | BOB         |    185 |
| 12 | 2006 | JANE        |     25 |
| 13 | 2006 | JOHN        |    207 |
+----+------+-------------+--------+
```

I am trying to add a new column that will track the year-over-year change of the amounts of each person:

```
+----+------+-------------+--------+-------+
| ID | YEAR | PERSON_NAME | AMOUNT | Y-O-Y |
+----+------+-------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | 2004 | BARBARA     |    500 |       |
|  2 | 2004 | BOB         |    100 |       |
|  3 | 2004 | JANE        |     30 |       |
|  4 | 2004 | JOHN        |    200 |       |
|  5 | 2005 | BARBARA     |    505 |     5 |
|  6 | 2005 | BOB         |    150 |    50 |
|  7 | 2005 | JANE        |     15 |   -15 |
|  8 | 2005 | JOHN        |    215 |    15 |
| 10 | 2006 | BARBARA     |    523 |    18 |
| 11 | 2006 | BOB         |    185 |    35 |
| 12 | 2006 | JANE        |     25 |    10 |
| 13 | 2006 | JOHN        |    207 |    -8 |
+----+------+-------------+--------+-------+
```

I've achieved this easily in SQL by joining the table to itself with some `ON` conditions, and was trying to mimic the same logic to c# `DataTable` and got it to somehow work in a convoluted way. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way with LINQ or `DataView`s or just a compact algorithm to achieve the same effect. Thanks!

Comment: Since the YOY change is a computed value and not a canonical value in your data, I'd recommend pushing that further downstream. Add it to your model class, or compute it on the fly in your controller or view as needed

Comment: Do you want to modify the source `DataTable` or create a new `DataTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("YEAR", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("PERSON_NAME", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("AMOUNT", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2004, "BARBARA", 500 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 2004, "BOB", 100 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 2004, "JANE", 30 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 2004, "JOHN", 200 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, 2005, "BARBARA", 505 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, 2005, "BOB", 150 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, 2005, "JANE", 15 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, 2005, "JOHN", 215 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10, 2006, "BARBARA", 523 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, 2006, "BOB", 185 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, 2006, "JANE", 25 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 13, 2006, "JOHN", 207 });

            dt.Columns.Add("Y-O-Y", typeof(int));

            List<List<DataRow>> groups =  dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Field<int>("YEAR"))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("PERSON_NAME"))
                .Select(x => x.ToList())
                .ToList();

            foreach (List<DataRow> person in groups)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < person.Count(); i++)
                {
                    person[i]["Y-O-Y"] = person[i].Field<int>("AMOUNT") - person[i - 1].Field<int>("AMOUNT");
                    //or
                    //person[i]["Y-O-Y"] = (int)person[i]["AMOUNT"] - (int)person[i - 1]["AMOUNT"];

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```